# How to change the width of box-shadow css

Tags: css, box-shadow

I have a button that has a box-shadow on hover.

**I dont know** how to make the box-shadow smaller in width.

I will attach the current status of my button:

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```css
.paddingButtons {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.paddingButtons:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 15px rgba(142, 84, 197, 0.6), inset 0 0 30px rgba(142, 84, 197, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 15px rgba(142, 84, 197, 0.6), inset 0 0 30px rgba(142, 84, 197, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 15px rgba(142, 84, 197, 0.6), inset 0 0 30px rgba(142, 84, 197, 1);
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.full-row {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="full-row margin-small">
    <a href="#" class="paddingButtons">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ilwpsig.png" class="default" width=80% />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: reduce the `15px`

Comment: Just look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: @TemaniAfif reducing that will also reduce the height of my shadow. Try using the codepen I provided, and you will see what im talking about

Comment: @Urel I know the basics of the shadow-box. Was trying to get smart with it. I think I am not using the box-shadow as intended.

Comment: remove the width=80% your are using for the image and chage the a to display:inline-block then you can keep only the inset shadow

Comment: @TemaniAfif U sir, deserve a cookie. Thank you. Please create an answer so I can accept it. Thank you, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your code like below.

```css
.paddingButtons {
  display:inline-block; /* to cover all the image */
}
img {
  display:block; /* to avoid white space at the bottom */
}

.paddingButtons:hover {
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 30px rgba(142, 84, 197, 1); /* only inset is needed */
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.full-row {
  grid-column: 1/4;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="full-row margin-small">
    <a href="#" class="paddingButtons">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ilwpsig.png" class="default" > <!-- removed width=80% -->
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```